# assembly code in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I need help with this code of assembly language

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.DATA
STRING1 db 5 DUP (?),"$"
.code
main proc

    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV ES, AX ; initialize ES
    LEA DI,[STRING1]         ; assume BYTE string
    CLD
    MOV AL, 'A'
    STOSB                   ; store 1st byte of A
    STOSB                   ; store 1st byte of A

    lea dx,STRING1
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

This instruction is to display two "aa" as an output but it is also showing me this:

[image: output]

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBB0R.png)

Comment: That entire first block of code, ending with `STOSB`, can be replaced with: `mov WORD PTR [string1], 'AA'`. This is simpler, faster, and less confusing.

Comment: maybe trying to programmatically work thorugh a string at runtime and this is just an example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: i had to use string instructions it is for the assignment but thank for your inputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Int 21/AH=09h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) needs the address of the string in **DS**:DX. You forgot to initialize `DS`.